# Bash script to convert from HTML entities to characters

Tags: html, bash, html-escape-characters

I'm looking for a way to turn this:

```
hello &lt; world
```

to this:

```
hello < world
```

I could use sed, but how can this be accomplished without using cryptic regex?

Answer (score 110):

Try [recode](http://www.gnu.org/software/recode/) ([archived page](https://web.archive.org/web/20110303232633/http://recode.progiciels-bpi.ca/); [GitHub mirror](https://github.com/pinard/Recode); [Debian page](https://packages.debian.org/en/sid/recode)):

```
$ echo '&lt;' |recode html..ascii
<
```

Install on Linux and similar Unix-y systems:

```
$ sudo apt-get install recode
```

Install on Mac OS using:

```
$ brew install recode
```

Comment: why do I get "recode: Untranslatable input in step `ANSI_X3.4-1968..ISO-10646-UCS-2'" when I try this the opposite way?

Comment: Just my 2 cents -- I convert XML encoded in UTF-8 and I use:
recode xml..utf8

Comment: Good for HTML entities but messes up emoji: `echo '' | recode html..UTF-8` gives `ð`. The Perl method retains them.

Comment: @Hugo If you encode your emoji in proper HTML, it will not be messed.

Comment: BTW to run this in place in a file, do `recode -i html..UTF-8 $file`

Comment: This is good, however it mangles unicode (`&amp; ٱلْعَرَبِيَّة` becomes `& Ù±ÙÙØ¹ÙØ±ÙØ¨ÙÙÙÙØ©`). The `perl` approach is preferred in situations like these.

Comment: `recode` assumes that HTML is encoded in ISO-8859 and will therefore break UTF-8: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=748984

Comment: `html..utf8` completely messes up basic already-encoded characters like `’` and `html...ascii` can be a mess too. user1788934’s answer with Perl is much better and doesn’t need anything to be installed.

Comment: @YatharthAgarwal `recode` supports just HTML 4. Use `recode -l` to get a list of supported encodings. My answer is from 2011. HTML5 is from 2014.

Comment: By “Unixy, you seem to mean Debiany. `apt` is only one of many package managers used on GNU systems, Linux kernel or not.

Answer (score 72):

With perl:

```
cat foo.html | perl -MHTML::Entities -pe 'decode_entities($_);'
```

With php from the command line:

```bash
cat foo.html | php -r 'while(($line=fgets(STDIN)) !== FALSE) echo html_entity_decode($line, ENT_QUOTES|ENT_HTML401);'
```

Comment: The PHP one is not working for certain characters such as `&nbsp;`

Comment: Shorter Perl version: `perl -MHTML::Entities -pe 'decode_entities($_);'`

Comment: I'll give you an upvote if you remove the useless use of cat (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_(Unix)#Useless_use_of_cat) :-)

Comment: Use `perl -C -MHTML::Entities -pe 'decode_entities($_);' < foo.html` to output UTF-8 (see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/627661/how-can-i-output-utf-8-from-perl))

Comment: 'cat is useless' comments are ill-considered. The reprimanded user may for example have been doing something like 'zcat FILE.gz | <intricate_command> just two command-lines before the current line, and 'gunzip FILE.gz' one command-line before the current. With history and readline, that user can now hit UPARROW twice, then hit HOME, delete one character (the 'z'), and hit ENTER to run the command that "cat useless" hecklers abhor. Ergo: 'cat is useless' comments are often less keen than they are clueless.

Comment: The Perl solution works even in Git Bash on Windows where `recode` is not available.

Answer (score 24):

An alternative is to pipe through a web browser -- such as:

`echo '&#33;' | w3m -dump -T text/html`

This worked great for me in cygwin, where downloading and installing distributions are difficult.

This answer was found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2262061/replacing-html-ascii-codes-via-a-bash-script#comment2223833_2262526)

Answer (score 20):

Using xmlstarlet:

```
echo 'hello &lt; world' | xmlstarlet unesc
```

Comment: Note that this does not work for hexa entities like `&#x3a;`.

Comment: It also fails for &quot;

Answer (score 19):

A python 3.2+ version:

```py
cat foo.html | python3 -c 'import html, sys; [print(html.unescape(l), end="") for l in sys.stdin]'
```

Comment: How to make this have effect in file? I mean, to replace in file?

Comment: Save the output directly on the file just add `[...] > foo.html` to the end of the command

Comment: Note that this tries to load lines into memory, and for each processed line, it adds an empty entry to an array. If you don't have long lines, replacing the `[... for x in y]` syntax with a regular `for x in y:\n\t...` loop will work.

Answer (score 16):

This answer is based on: [Short way to escape HTML in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12873682/short-way-to-escape-html-in-bash) which works fine for grabbing answers (using `wget`) on Stack Exchange and converting HTML to regular ASCII characters:

```bash
sed 's/&nbsp;/ /g; s/&amp;/\&/g; s/&lt;/\</g; s/&gt;/\>/g; s/&quot;/\"/g; s/#&#39;/\'"'"'/g; s/&ldquo;/\"/g; s/&rdquo;/\"/g;'
```

**Edit 1:** April 7, 2017 - Added left double quote and right double quote conversion. This is part of bash script that web-scrapes SE answers and compares them to local code files here: [Ask Ubuntu -
Code Version Control between local files and Ask Ubuntu answers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/900319/code-version-control-between-local-files-and-au-answers)

---

### Edit June 26, 2017

Using `sed` was taking ~3 seconds to convert HTML to ASCII on a 1K line file from Ask Ubuntu / Stack Exchange. As such I was forced to use Bash built-in search and replace for ~1 second response time.

Here's the function:

```bash
LineOut=""      # Make global
HTMLtoText () {
    LineOut=$1  # Parm 1= Input line
    # Replace external command: Line=$(sed 's/&amp;/\&/g; s/&lt;/\</g; 
    # s/&gt;/\>/g; s/&quot;/\"/g; s/&#39;/\'"'"'/g; s/&ldquo;/\"/g; 
    # s/&rdquo;/\"/g;' <<< "$Line") -- With faster builtin commands.
    LineOut="${LineOut//&nbsp;/ }"
    LineOut="${LineOut//&amp;/&}"
    LineOut="${LineOut//&lt;/<}"
    LineOut="${LineOut//&gt;/>}"
    LineOut="${LineOut//&quot;/'"'}"
    LineOut="${LineOut//&#39;/"'"}"
    LineOut="${LineOut//&ldquo;/'"'}" # TODO: ASCII/ISO for opening quote
    LineOut="${LineOut//&rdquo;/'"'}" # TODO: ASCII/ISO for closing quote
} # HTMLtoText ()
```

Comment: On macOS Mohave with the default bash / sed, the `HTMLtoText` function wasn't doing the right thing with quotes (it would emit e.g. `'"'`) and I couldn't get it to work, The original sed function worked correctly, though.

Comment: It may work for specific use cases, but it is not a general solution. For example `&#60;` is not unescaped into `<`.

Comment: The replacement of `&amp;` must be the last replacement. Test with input of `'&amp;lt;'`. The result should be `&lt;` not `<`. Both the sed and the bash solution offered have this problem.

Answer (score 6):

On macOS, you can use the built-in command `textutil` (which is a handy utility in general):

```sh
echo '&#128075; hello &lt; world &#x1f310;' | textutil -convert txt -format html -stdin -stdout
```

outputs:

```
 hello < world
```

Comment: Just a note that you may need to provide a hint to `textutil` about input encoding for it to work correctly. e.g. `echo "здравствуйте &lt; мир" | textutil -convert txt -format html -stdin -stdout -inputencoding 4`

Answer (score 1):

To support the unescaping of all HTML entities only with sed substitutions would require too long a list of commands to be practical, because every Unicode code point has at least two corresponding HTML entities.

But it can be done using only sed, grep, the Bourne shell and basic UNIX utilities (the GNU coreutils or equivalent):

```
#!/bin/sh

htmlEscDec2Hex() {
    file=$1
    [ ! -r "$file" ] && file=$(mktemp) && cat >"$file"

    printf -- \
        "$(sed 's/\\/\\\\/g;s/%/%%/g;s/&#[0-9]\{1,10\};/\&#x%x;/g' "$file")\n" \
        $(grep -o '&#[0-9]\{1,10\};' "$file" | tr -d '&#;')

    [ x"$1" != x"$file" ] && rm -f -- "$file"
}

htmlHexUnescape() {
    printf -- "$(
        sed 's/\\/\\\\/g;s/%/%%/g
            ;s/&#x\([0-9a-fA-F]\{1,8\}\);/\&#x0000000\1;/g
            ;s/&#x0*\([0-9a-fA-F]\{4\}\);/\\u\1/g
            ;s/&#x0*\([0-9a-fA-F]\{8\}\);/\\U\1/g' )\n"
}

htmlEscDec2Hex "$1" | htmlHexUnescape \
    | sed -f named_entities.sed
```

Note, however, that a printf implementation supporting `\uHHHH` and `\UHHHHHHHH` sequences is required, such as the GNU utility’s. To test, check for example that `printf "\u00A7\n"` prints `§`. To call the utility instead of the shell built-in, replace the occurrences of `printf` with `env printf`.

This script uses an additional file, `named_entities.sed`, in order to support the named entities. It can be generated from the specification using the following HTML page:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head><meta charset="utf-8" /></head>
<body>
<p id="sed-script"></p>
<script type="text/javascript">
  const referenceURL = 'https://html.spec.whatwg.org/entities.json';

  function writeln(element, text) {
    element.appendChild( document.createTextNode(text) );
    element.appendChild( document.createElement("br") );
  }

  (async function(container) {
    const json = await (await fetch(referenceURL)).json();
    container.innerHTML = "";
    writeln(container, "#!/usr/bin/sed -f");
    const addLast = [];
    for (const name in json) {
      const characters = json[name].characters
        .replace("\\", "\\\\")
        .replace("/", "\\/");
      const command = "s/" + name + "/" + characters + "/g";
      if ( name.endsWith(";") ) {
        writeln(container, command);
      } else {
        addLast.push(command);
      }
    }
    for (const command of addLast) { writeln(container, command); }
  })( document.getElementById("sed-script") );
</script>
</body></html>
```

Simply open it in a modern browser, and save the resulting page as text as `named_entities.sed`. This sed script can also be used alone if only named entities are required; in this case it is convenient to give it executable permission so that it can be called directly.

Now the above shell script can be used as `./html_unescape.sh foo.html`, or inside a pipeline reading from standard input.

For example, if for some reason it is needed to process the data by chunks (it might be the case if `printf` is not a shell built-in and the data to process is large), one could use it as:

```
nLines=20
seq 1 $nLines $(grep -c $ "$inputFile") | while read n
    do sed -n "$n,$((n+nLines-1))p" "$inputFile" | ./html_unescape.sh
done
```

---

Explanation of the script follows.

There are three types of escape sequences that need to be supported:

1. `&#D;` where `D` is the decimal value of the escaped character’s Unicode code point;
2. `&#xH;` where `H` is the hexadecimal value of the escaped character’s Unicode code point;
3. `&N;` where `N` is the name of one of the named entities for the escaped character.

The `&N;` escapes are supported by the generated `named_entities.sed` script which simply performs the list of substitutions.

The central piece of this method for supporting the code point escapes is the `printf` utility, which is able to:

1. print numbers in hexadecimal format, and
2. print characters from their code point’s hexadecimal value (using the escapes `\uHHHH` or `\UHHHHHHHH`).

The first feature, with some help from sed and grep, is used to reduce the `&#D;` escapes into `&#xH;` escapes. The shell function `htmlEscDec2Hex` does that.

The function `htmlHexUnescape` uses sed to transform the `&#xH;` escapes into printf’s `\u`/`\U` escapes, then uses the second feature to print the unescaped characters.

Answer (score 1):

I like the Perl answer given in https://stackoverflow.com/a/13161719/1506477.

```
cat foo.html | perl -MHTML::Entities -pe 'decode_entities($_);'
```

But, it produced an unequal number of lines on plain text files. (and I dont know perl enough to debug it.)

I like the python answer given in https://stackoverflow.com/a/42672936/1506477 --

```py
python3 -c 'import html, sys; [print(html.unescape(l), end="") for l in sys.stdin]'
```

but it creates a list `[ ... for l in sys.stdin]` in memory, that is forbidden for large files.

**Here is another easy pythonic way without buffering in memory: using `awkg`.**

```
$ echo 'hello &lt; &#x3a; &quot; world' | \
   awkg -b 'from html import unescape' 'print(unescape(R0))'
hello < : " world
```

`awkg` is a python based awk-like line processor. You may install it using pip https://pypi.org/project/awkg/:

```
pip install awkg
```

`-b` is awk's `BEGIN{}` block that runs once in the beginning.
Here we just did `from html import unescape`.

Each line record is in `R0` variable, for which we did
`print(unescape(R0))`

Disclaimer:
I am the maintainer of `awkg`

Answer (score 0):

I have created a [`sed` script](https://gist.github.com/Ajnasz/8d2ab713916be7790ebf303a5dd6f7d6)  based on the [list of entities](https://www.freeformatter.com/html-entities.html) so it must handle most of the entities.

```
sed -f htmlentities.sed < file.html
```

Comment: The script does not handle the hexadecimal entities, and at least 2000 named entities. Of course it does not handle all the decimal entities either (such as &#12398;). See my answer above for a complete solution.
Lastly, the input redirection < is not needed when invoking sed.

Comment: @unagi Oh god, why didn't you just put it somewhere as a downloadable script with short explanation? :) It would save me some minutes of work.I didn't even read through the answer as there was two different thing, where the first I guess doesn't handle the named entities and the second was an html/javascript code what I didn't want to involve as I just wanted a simple sed script. :)

Answer (score 0):

My original answer got some comments, that `recode` does not work for UTF-8 encoded HTML files. This is correct. `recode` supports only HTML 4. The encoding `HTML` is an alias for `HTML_4.0`:

```
$ recode -l | grep -iw html
HTML-i18n 2070 RFC2070
HTML_4.0 h h4 HTML
```

The default encoding for HTML 4 is Latin-1. This has changed in HTML 5. The default encoding for HTML 5 is UTF-8. This is the reason, why `recode` does not work for HTML 5 files.

HTML 5 defines the list of entities here:

- https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/named-characters.html

The definition includes a machine readable specification in JSON format:

- https://html.spec.whatwg.org/entities.json

The JSON file can be used to perform a simple text replacement. The following example is a self modifying Perl script, which caches the JSON specification in its DATA chunk.

**Note:** For some obscure compatibility reasons, the specification allows entities without a terminating semicolon. Because of that the entities are sorted by length in reverse order to make sure, that the correct entities are replaced first so that they do not get destroyed by entities without the ending semicolon.

```perl
#! /usr/bin/perl
use utf8;
use strict;
use warnings;
use open qw(:std :utf8);
use LWP::Simple;
use JSON::Parse qw(parse_json);

my $entities;

INIT {
  if (eof DATA) {
    my $data = tell DATA;
    open DATA, '+<', $0;
    seek DATA, $data, 0;
    my $entities_json = get 'https://html.spec.whatwg.org/entities.json';
    print DATA $entities_json;
    truncate DATA, tell DATA;
    close DATA;
    $entities = parse_json ($entities_json);
  } else {
    local $/ = undef;
    $entities = parse_json (<DATA>);
  }
}

local $/ = undef;
my $html = <>;

for my $entity (sort { length $b <=> length $a } keys %$entities) {
  my $characters = $entities->{$entity}->{characters};
  $html =~ s/$entity/$characters/g;
}

print $html;

__DATA__
```

Example usage:

```
$ echo '&nbsp;&amp;&nbsp;ٱلْعَرَبِيَّة' | ./html5-to-utf8.pl
 & ٱلْعَرَبِيَّة
```

Answer (score 0):

Also I found this one solution:

````bash
#!/bin/bash

LineOut=""      # Make global
HTMLtoText () {
    LineOut=$1  # Parm 1= Input line
    # Replace external command: Line=$(sed 's/&amp;/\&/g; s/&lt;/\</g; 
    # s/&gt;/\>/g; s/&quot;/\"/g; s/&#39;/\'"'"'/g; s/&ldquo;/\"/g; 
    # s/&rdquo;/\"/g;' <<< "$Line") -- With faster builtin commands.
    LineOut="${LineOut//&nbsp;/ }"
    LineOut="${LineOut//&amp;/&}"
    LineOut="${LineOut//&lt;/<}"
    LineOut="${LineOut//&gt;/>}"
    LineOut="${LineOut//&quot;/'"'}"
    LineOut="${LineOut//&#39;/"'"}"
    LineOut="${LineOut//&#039;/"'"}"
    LineOut="${LineOut//&ldquo;/'"'}" # TODO: ASCII/ISO for opening quote
    LineOut="${LineOut//&rdquo;/'"'}" # TODO: ASCII/ISO for closing quote
} # HTMLtoText ()

[ -n "$1" ] && HTMLtoText "$1" && echo "$LineOut" && exit 0 || echo "no arg(s)" && echo chk && exit 1```
````

Answer (score -1):

With [Xidel](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/xidel.html):

```
echo 'hello &lt; &#x3a; &quot; world' | xidel -s - -e 'parse-html($raw)'
hello < : " world
```