# Short way to escape HTML in Bash?

Tags: bash, html-entities

The box has no Ruby/Python/Perl etc.

Only `bash`, `sed`, and `awk`.

A way is to replace chars by map, but it becomes tedious.

Perhaps some built-in functionality i'm not aware of?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Escaping HTML really just involves replacing three characters: `<`, `>`, and `&`. For extra points, you can also replace `"` and `'`. So, it's not a long `sed` script:

```
sed 's/&/\&amp;/g; s/</\&lt;/g; s/>/\&gt;/g; s/"/\&quot;/g; s/'"'"'/\&#39;/g'
```

Comment: +1 for elegance and efficiency. You should post your answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5929492/bash-script-to-convert-from-html-entities-to-characters where they recommend installing `recode`, `perl`, `php`, `xmlsarlet` and `w3m` (a web browser for crying out loud). The last answer recommends using Python3 which although installed by default (in Ubuntu at least) is overkill too.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix: Thanks for your kind words! That question is asking about the opposite direction (`&lt;` to `<`), and the answers there are trying to cover the possibility of random other entity references like `&eacute;` and numeric character references like `&#xC9;`, rather than minimally-escaped HTML. For many purposes that might be overengineering, but on Stack Overflow it can be hard to tell exactly what someone's purpose is, so I don't blame the answerers there for wanting to provide something universal.

Comment: @ruakh You're welcome :) Can't your sed search and replace simply be reversed to accomplish the same result as those answers?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix: There are many ways to HTML-escape a given piece of text; for example, `&lt;`, `&#x3C;`, and `&#60;` are all valid ways to escape `<`. My `sed` script only does one kind of HTML-escaping, since you only need one; but if you want to do HTML-*unescaping*, then either you need to handle all valid ways of escaping, or you need to know beforehand exactly what way of escaping was used. Do you see what I mean?

Comment: Yes. My HTML-unescaping is limited to stack exchange site Ask Ubuntu and so far I've only noticed `&Amp;`, `$lt;` and `&quot;`. The goal is to compare all the scripts on my drive I've published in Ask Ubuntu to see if they have been changed locally or revised by someone else in Ask Ubuntu. For fun I'm also extracting upvotes from the HTML file and putting it in the local file. This is the work in progress from a few nights ago: http://askubuntu.com/questions/894888/bash-template-to-use-zenity-or-yad-to-insert-edit-delete-records-in-a-file/896783#896783

Comment: Really useful. Same as a function: `escape_html() { sed $1 's/&/\&amp;/g; s/</\&lt;/g; s/>/\&gt;/g; s/"/\&quot;/g; s/'"'"'/\&#39;/g'; }`

Answer (score 16):

You can use `recode` utility:

```
    echo 'He said: "Not sure that - 2<1"' | recode ascii..html
```

Output:

```
    He said: &quot;Not sure that - 2&lt;1&quot;
```

Comment: Probably not available if there's no Python/Ruby/Perl.

Comment: Tested on 30 or so textfiles containing ASCII and it even handles the null character `\0`. Use to sandbox textfile contents for `srcdoc` attribute of a sandboxed `iframe` in HTML and allow background styling via parent frame to cascade.

Answer (score 14):

Pure bash, no external programs:

```
function htmlEscape () {
    local s
    s=${1//&/&amp;}
    s=${s//</&lt;}
    s=${s//>/&gt;}
    s=${s//'"'/&quot;}
    printf -- %s "$s"
}
```

Just simple string substitution.

Answer (score 3):

I'm using [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/):

```sh
$ echo "2 < 4 is 'TRUE'" | jq -Rr @html
2 &lt; 4 is &apos;TRUE&apos;
```

Answer (score 2):

or use xmlstar [Escape/Unescape special XML characters](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/xmlstarlet-ug.html#idm47077139540960):

```
$ echo '<abc&def>'| xml esc
&lt;abc&amp;def&gt;
```

Comment: I want to try this but I don't know how to install xml esc. I don't even know what it is. Could you elaborate?

Comment: Just `brew install xmlstarlet` if you are using MacOS.

Answer (score 2):

This is an updated answer to miken32 "Pure bash, "*no external programs*":

bash 5.2 breaks backward compatibility in ways that are highly inconvenient.

From NEWS:

> x. New shell option: **patsub_replacement**. When enabled, a '&' in
> the replacement string of the pattern substitution expansion is
> replaced by the portion of the string that matched the pattern.
> Backslash will escape the '&' and insert a literal '&'.
>
> The option is enabled by default. If you want to restore the previous
> behavior, add **shopt -u patsub_replacement**.

So there is three ways to use miken32 code in bash 5.2+:

Either disable **patsub_replacement**:

```
shopt -u patsub_replacement
function htmlEscape () {
    local s
    s=${1//&/&amp;}
    s=${s//</&lt;}
    s=${s//>/&gt;}
    s=${s//'"'/&quot;}
    printf -- %s "$s"
}
```

, another option is to escape '&' with backslash in the replacement if you want to make it work regardless of the 5.2 feature, **patsub_replacement**:

```
function htmlEscape () {
    local s
    s=${1//&/\&amp;}
    s=${s//</\&lt;}
    s=${s//>/\&gt;}
    s=${s//'"'/\&quot;}
    printf -- %s "$s"
}
```

and another option is to quote string in the replacement:

```
function htmlEscape () {
    local s
    s=${1//&/"&amp;"}
    s=${s//</"&lt;"}
    s=${s//>/"&gt;"}
    s=${s//'"'/"&quot;"}
    printf -- %s "$s"
}
```

Answer (score -1):

There's much better answers, but I just found this so I thought I'd share.

```
PN=`basename "$0"`          # Program name
VER=`echo '$Revision: 1.1 $' | cut -d' ' -f2`

Usage () {
    echo >&2 "$PN - encode HTML unsave characters, $VER
usage: $PN [file ...]"
    exit 1
}

set -- `getopt h "$@"`
while [ $# -gt 0 ]
do
    case "$1" in
    --) shift; break;;
    -h) Usage;;
    -*) Usage;;
    *)  break;;         # First file name
    esac
    shift
done

sed                                     \
    -e 's/&/\&amp;/g'                       \
    -e 's/"/\&quot;/g'                      \
    -e 's/</\&lt;/g'                        \
    -e 's/>/\&gt;/g'                        \
    -e 's/„/\&auml;/g'                      \
    -e 's/Ž/\&Auml;/g'                      \
    -e 's/”/\&ouml;/g'                      \
    -e 's/™/\&Ouml;/g'                      \
    -e 's//\&uuml;/g'                       \
    -e 's/š/\&Uuml;/g'                      \
    -e 's/á/\&szlig;/g'                     \
    "$@"
```

Comment: Most of these replacements are very wrong, and entities for Unicode characters are generally not needed any longer. Even so, there are hundreds of entities defined in HTML; why have you chosen these half dozen to incorrectly replace??

Comment: @miken32 `"but I just found this so I thought I'd share"`   
I found it while looking for resolutions, I didn't write it. It worked for me so I shared it.

Answer (score -5):

The previous sed replacement defaces valid output like

```
&lt;
```

into

```
&amp;lt;
```

Adding a negative loook-ahead so "&" is only changed into "&amp;" if that "&" isn't already followed by "amp;" fixes that:

```
sed 's/&(?!amp;)/\&amp;/g; s/</\&lt;/g; s/>/\&gt;/g; s/"/\&quot;/g; s/'"'"'/\&#39;/g'
```

Comment: Big mistake. When I HTML-encode a string `&amp;`, it is because I want it to be rendered by some web browser as `&amp;`. That is why it **must** be turned into `&amp;amp;`. That way, HTML-encoding and HTML-decoding are in balance. You don't suppress HTML-encoding just because the input _looks like_ it has already been HTML-encoded. HTML-encoding is **not** idempotent. Failure to grasp that, eventually leads to XSS vulnerabilities.

Comment: @Ruud is right; the right way to accomplish this is to escape ampersands first, like in ruakh's answer.

Comment: I totally agree with what @Ruud said except that he should have emphasized **failure to grasp that leads to XSS vulnerabilities**