# How to send file contents to a function?

Tags: bash

I want to send the XML (HTML) content I get from a file to a substitution function so I can fix the wrong HTML entities (and overwrite the file). But I am not able to do it

This is the function based [another answer I found](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52570455/1255819)

```
function htmlEscape () {
    local s=$1
    s=${1//&/&amp;}
    s=${s//</&lt;}
    s=${s//>/&gt;}
    s=${s//'"'/&quot;}
    echo $s
}
```

I tried

```
cat $TEMPFILEPATH | htmlEscape > $TEMPFILEPATH 
tee $TEMPFILEPATH <<< htmlEscape "$(cat $TEMPFILEPATH)"
```

But those do not work. I am really really really new with bash scripts. Does anyone can help me?

Comment: Have you testex `html2text` ?

Comment: You are "sending" file content correctly in the first line. But you are not `read`ing it. The second line with `tee` makes no sense.

Comment: Note that `> $TEMPFILEPATH` may truncate the file before `cat` has a chance to read the entire contents.

Comment: You should probably create the function as a set of sed commands and pipe it through there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote your function to accept an argument:

```
htmlEscape "$(cat $TEMPFILEPATH)"
```

You can move the `cat` command inside the function, though:

```
htmlEscape () {
    local s=$(cat "$1")
    s=${1//&/&amp;}
    s=${s//</&lt;}
    s=${s//>/&gt;}
    s=${s//'"'/&quot;}
    echo "$s"
}

htmlEscape "$TEMPFILEPATH"
```

Comment: @WalterA I think you mean `htmlEscape "$TEMPFILEPATH" > "$TEMPFILEPATH.out"`

Answer (score 1):

I would create a `sed` script 'htmlEscape.sed'

```
s/&/&amp;/g
s/</&lt;/g
s/>/&gt;/g
s/"/&quot;/g
```

which you can then use by piping

```
cat $TEMPFILEPATH | sed -f htmlEscape.sed
```

or with the appropriate sed

```
sed -i -f htmlEscape.sed $TEMPFILEPATH
```