# Shell/Bash - extra characters in string variable after assigning cli result

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, shell, command-line-interface

In one of my variables I store result (string) from aws cli command.
When echoing the value it is displayed in `" "` but injecting it as a parameter shows that extra characters (`&#34`) are added at the beginning and end of the string.

How to eliminate these? What do they represent?

Code and error log:

```
dms_arn=$(aws dms describe-replication-tasks --filter Name=replication-task-id,Values="$dms_name" `--query=ReplicationTasks[0].ReplicationTaskArn --region us-east-1)`
echo Stopping Task "$dms_arn"


build   02-Nov-2021 18:52:01    Stopping Task "arn:aws:dms:us-east-1:account:task:XYZ"
error   02-Nov-2021 18:52:02    
error   02-Nov-2021 18:52:02    An error occurred (InvalidParameterValueException) when calling the StopReplicationTask operation: Invalid task ARN:  &#34;arn:aws:dms:us-east-1:account:task:XYZ&#34;
```

Comment: [They represent quotes.](https://www.codetable.net/decimal/34) So you need to figure out what is generating and escaping them and why. It looks like the output is meant for a browser or the like.

Comment: BTW, if you want to just trim 5 leading and 5 trailing characters from a string, that would be `dms_arn='&#34;arn:aws:dms:us-east-1:account:task:XYZ&#34;'; echo "${dms_arn:5:-5}"`.

Comment: It's a denotation of [HTML entities](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`&#34` is the html code for double quote (`"`). The double quotes are being converted to html code.

Try using the `—output text` option with your `aws` command (so you don’t get quotes). See the documentation about output format: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-usage-output-format.html

If necessary, you can remove wrapping double quotes using shell parameter expansion:

```
dms_arn=${dms_arn%\"}
dms_arn=${dms_arn#\"}

echo "$dms_arn"
# quotes are gone
```

Comment: `--output text` did the trick! :)

Answer (score 2):

`&#34` is the *HTML entity* corresponding to the double quotation marks.

See: [entity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Entity)

To convert them check: [Short way to escape HTML in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12873682/short-way-to-escape-html-in-bash/12873723?noredirect=1#comment73158338_12873723) and [Bash script to convert from HTML entities to characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5929492/bash-script-to-convert-from-html-entities-to-characters/5929519)