# Substring of string in bash

Tags: regex, bash, substring, cut

I have a variable `b`:

```
name=John&login=John99
```

`John` and `John99` are not a constant. I would like to put substring of `b` in another varriable so when I type this statement in bash:

- `echo $variable` it will print `John`
- `echo $variable2` it will    print `John99`

I would be grateful for help.

Comment: Do you want to do http query decoding? In that case using a library is more appropriate since the encoding uses *percentage-encoding* as well.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you only care about plain ASCII characters and not entity encoding:

```
variable=${b#*name=}          # trim everything up to and including "name=" in b
variable=${variable%%"&"*}    # trim everything following first "&" in variable

variable2=${b#*login=}        # trim everything up to and including "login=" in b
variable2=${variable2$$"&"*}  # trim everything following first "&" in variable2
```

Alternately, if you *really* want to use regular expressions, you can do so as follows:

```
re_name='name=([^$]+)([&]|$)'
[[ $b =~ $re_name ]] && variable=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
re_login='login=([^$]+)([&]|$)'
[[ $b =~ $re_login ]] && variable2=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
```

References:

- [The Bash-Hackers page on parameter expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe)
- [BashFAQ #100 ("How do I do string manipulations in bash?")](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100)
- [The BashGuide page on Patterns](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Patterns#Regular_Expressions-1) (describing `=~`)

Also, if you *do* want to do HTML entity decoding, see [Bash script to convert from HTML entities to characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5929492/bash-script-to-convert-from-html-entities-to-characters)