# Modify sed command to catch substrings

Tags: regex, bash, sed, grep

I have the example text:

```
"are &quot;insulin sensitizers&quot; "
```

I am trying to use the below command to find and replace the xml quote command with a single quote but it only works for the first one and the second that follows "sensitizers" is left unchanged.

command:

```
grep -rl "&quot;" ./ | xargs sed -i "s/&quot;/'/"
```

result:

```
"are 'insulin sensitizers&quot; "
```

desired result:

```
"are 'insulin sensitizers' "
```

Comment: `sed -i "s/&quot;/'/g"` (global)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bash script to convert from HTML entities to characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5929492/bash-script-to-convert-from-html-entities-to-characters). Amusingly, the question ends with "*how can this be accomplished without using cryptic regex?*"

Comment: cryptic regex could be a great supervillain, @anubhava if you'd like to put your comment as an answer I woud be happy to accept it as it has solved my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use `g` flag in `sed` for global substitution:

```
grep -Zirl "&quot;" . | xargs -0 sed -i "s/&quot;/'/g"
```

Also note use of `-Z` option in `grep` and `-0` in `xargs` to take care of files with special characters and whitespaces.

As per `man grep`:

> `-Z`, `--null`
>
> Output  a zero byte (the ASCII NUL character) instead of the character that normally follows a file name.