# How to extraxt HTML elements from inside the "content:encoded" part of an RSS feed?

Tags: html, xml, xml-parsing, html-parsing, xmlstarlet

I am trying to generate a newsletter which, among other stuff, includes news entries which are present on the website as well. The website is built with WordPress and has an RSS feed, which is not actively used but now comes handy to parse the news entries.

I am writing a simple generator script in Bash using xmlstarlet. In particular I am able to get the title, the description and the URL for the news entries (I iterate over them using `$itemnum` as index):

```
TITLE=$(xmlstarlet sel -t -m "/rss/channel/item[$itemnum]" -v "title" feed.xml);
DESC=$(xmlstarlet sel -t -m "/rss/channel/item[$itemnum]" -v "description" feed.xml);
URL=$(xmlstarlet sel -t -m "/rss/channel/item[$itemnum]" -v "link" feed.xml);
```

But now I also want to get the URL for the thumbnail and the date of the news entry. Those are basically two different questions so I only ask about the thumbnail URL (regarding the date: it is easy to get from `<pubDate>...</pubDate>` but it is not localized). The URL is sitting in the `<content:encoded>...</content:encoded>` tag, which includes a lot of different HTML tags.

I know that xmlstarlet has a HTML option, but don't know how to use it when the HTML is embedded inside an XML element. If I try to parse the output of

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -m "/rss/channel/item[$itemnum]" -v "content:encoded" feed.xml | xmlstarlet sel -t -c "//img[@class='size-medium wp-image-2821 alignright'][1]"
```

it gives errors:

```
-:1.1: Start tag expected, '<' not found
&lt;div&gt;
^
```

The reason might be that when getting

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -m "/rss/channel/item[$itemnum]" -v "content:encoded" feed.xml
```

it translates all tag brackets `<` and `>` into `&lt;` and `&gt;` and I don't know how to work around it.

edit:

Here is how a news entry looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><rss version="2.0"
    xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/"
    xmlns:wfw="http://wellformedweb.org/CommentAPI/"
    xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
    xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
    xmlns:sy="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/syndication/"
    xmlns:slash="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/slash/"
    
    xmlns:georss="http://www.georss.org/georss"
    xmlns:geo="http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#"
    >

<channel>
    <title>This is the title</title>
    <atom:link href="https://link.to/feed" rel="self" type="application/rss+xml" />
    <link>https://website.url</link>
    <description>This is the description</description>
    <lastBuildDate>Wed, 20 Dec 2023 04:49:30 +0000</lastBuildDate>
    <language>de-DE</language>
    <sy:updatePeriod>
    hourly  </sy:updatePeriod>
    <sy:updateFrequency>
    1   </sy:updateFrequency>
    <generator>https://wordpress.org/?v=6.3.2</generator>
<site xmlns="com-wordpress:feed-additions:1">124249965</site>   

<item>
        <title>A title</title>
        <link>https://link.to/the-news-entry</link>
        
        <dc:creator><![CDATA[HP-Admin]]></dc:creator>
        <pubDate>Wed, 20 Dec 2023 04:49:30 +0000</pubDate>
                <category><![CDATA[Uncategorized]]></category>
        <guid isPermaLink="false">https://perma.link/p123</guid>

                    <description><![CDATA[a short description]]></description>
                                        <content:encoded><![CDATA[<p>A paragraph is written here.</p>
<p>Another paragraph is written here.</p>
<p><img decoding="async" fetchpriority="high" class="size-medium wp-image-2821 alignright" src="https://link.to/first-image.jpg" alt="" width="200" height="300" srcset="https://link.to/first-image.jpg 200w, https://link.to/first-image.jpg 683w, https://link.to/first-image.jpg 768w, https://link.to/first-image.jpg 1024w, https://link.to/first-image.jpg 1365w, https://link.to/first-image.jpg 367w, https://link.to/first-image.jpg 16w, https://link.to/first-image.jpg 24w, https://link.to/first-image.jpg 32w, https://link.to/first-image.jpg 1707w" sizes="(max-width: 200px) 100vw, 200px" /></p>
<p><img decoding="async" class="size-medium wp-image-2820 alignright" src="https://link.to/second-image.jpg" alt="" width="200" height="300" srcset="https://link.to/second-image.jpg 200w, https://link.to/second-image.jpg 683w, https://link.to/second-image.jpg 768w, https://link.to/second-image.jpg 1024w, https://link.to/second-image.jpg 1365w, https://link.to/second-image.jpg 367w, https://link.to/second-image.jpg 16w, https://link.to/second-image.jpg 24w, https://link.to/second-image.jpg 32w, https://link.to/second-image.jpg 1707w" sizes="(max-width: 200px) 100vw, 200px" /></p>
<p>Another paragraph is written here.</p>
<p>Another paragraph is written here.</p>
<p>Another paragraph is written here.</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
]]></content:encoded>
                    
        
        
        <post-id xmlns="com-wordpress:feed-additions:1">2818</post-id>  </item>
    </channel>
</rss>
```

Now I noticed that both images are not actually the header image I need... The URL to the header image does not appear in the feed xml at all... I'm really puzzled why this happens.

Comment: Hard to help without a minimum valid sample of the rss.

Comment: Look at the rss feed source, the html fragment is already encoded. https://stackoverflow.com/a/5935781/2834978

Comment: @LMC Sorry, I posted a news entry in question now (copied directly from the feed code, not processed with xmlstarlet yet)!  I now noticed that the URL I need to parse isn't even included there, that's really weird...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extract the simple variables, for example:

```sh
# shellcheck shell=sh disable=SC2016

xmlstarlet select -T -t \
  --var idx -o "${itemnum:-1}" -b \
  --var q1 -o "'" -b \
  -m '/rss/channel/item[$idx]' \
    -v 'concat("title=",$q1,str:replace(title,$q1,concat($q1,"\",$q1,$q1)),$q1)' -n \
    -v 'concat("desc=",$q1,str:replace(description,$q1,concat($q1,"\",$q1,$q1)),$q1)' -n \
    -v 'concat("url=",$q1,link,$q1)' -n \
    -v 'concat("pubdate=",$q1,pubDate,$q1)' -n \
feed.xml
```

where

- [`xmlstarlet select`](https://fossies.org/linux/xmlstarlet/doc/xmlstarlet-ug.html#idm47077139652416)'s  `-T` (aka `--text`) option is used for plaintext output
- `--var` defines a named variable, see
  [`xmlstarlet.txt`](https://fossies.org/linux/xmlstarlet/doc/xmlstarlet.txt) for examples
- the `itemnum` shell variable is passed in using
  shell [parameter expansion](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02)
- any embedded single quote characters in the `title` and `description`
  elements are quoted (see example in output) using the
  EXSLT [str:replace](https://exslt.github.io/str/functions/replace/index.html) function

Output:

```sh
title='A '\''modified'\'' title'
desc='a short description'
url='https://link.to/the-news-entry'
pubdate='Wed, 20 Dec 2023 04:49:30 +0000'
```

With GNU `date` localize with e.g. `date -Isec -d "${pubdate}"`.

To extract the image URLs from the embedded HTML, for example:

```sh
# shellcheck shell=sh disable=SC2016

xmlstarlet select -T -t \
  --var idx -o "${itemnum:-1}" -b \
  -v '/rss/channel/item[$idx]/content:encoded' \
feed.xml |
xmlstarlet format -R -H -D |
# tee /dev/stderr |
xmlstarlet select -T -t \
  --var cls -o "${class:-wp-image-2821}" -b \
  --var q1 -o "'" -b \
   -m 'str:split(//img[contains(@class,$cls)]/@srcset,",")' \
     --var url_sz='str:split(.," ")' \
     -v 'concat("url_",$url_sz[2],"=",$q1,$url_sz[1],"?width=",substring-before($url_sz[2],"w"),$q1)' -n
```

- use [`xmlstarlet select`](https://fossies.org/linux/xmlstarlet/doc/xmlstarlet-ug.html#idm47077139652416)'s  `-T` (aka `--text`) option for plaintext output
- shell variables `itemnum` and `class` are passed in using
  shell [parameter expansion](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02)
- use [`xmlstarlet format`](https://fossies.org/linux/xmlstarlet/doc/xmlstarlet-ug.html#idm47077139569312)
  `--recover --html --drop-dtd` to convert
  HTML 4.0 to XML, note that HTML entities such as `&nbsp;` are
  converted (uncomment the `tee` line to have a look)
- use `xmlstarlet select` and the XPath [`contains`](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116#function-contains)
  function to extract the appropriate `img/@srcset` text,
  [`str:split`](https://exslt.github.io/str/functions/split/index.html) it, first by comma then by space,
  and [`concat`](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116#function-concat) the
  [`substring`](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116#function-substring-before)s to a useful format

Output:

```sh
url_200w='https://link.to/first-image.jpg?width=200'
url_683w='https://link.to/first-image.jpg?width=683'
url_768w='https://link.to/first-image.jpg?width=768'
url_1024w='https://link.to/first-image.jpg?width=1024'
url_1365w='https://link.to/first-image.jpg?width=1365'
url_367w='https://link.to/first-image.jpg?width=367'
url_16w='https://link.to/first-image.jpg?width=16'
url_24w='https://link.to/first-image.jpg?width=24'
url_32w='https://link.to/first-image.jpg?width=32'
url_1707w='https://link.to/first-image.jpg?width=1707'
```

Comment: Thanks! As it turned out that the feed doesn't actually include the preview image, I had to parse the post list HTML code to get it. I ended up using what is proposed in https://www.howtogeek.com/devops/parsing-html-in-bash/ and then grep the output for `"img src='"`, then  `cut -d "'"` to get the actual URL. Luckily just the preview images had the src value set in single quotes, while other images used double quotes. For the date field I ended up with `DATE=$(date +"%d. %B %Y" -d "${DATE}");` to get something like 02. January 2024, thanks for the hint.

Comment: @Photon: Well, better to use a dedicated parser if at all possible. W3C's [`HTML-XML-utils`](https://www.w3.org/Tools/HTML-XML-utils/man1/) are HTML-aware and / or XML-aware. The [`hxwls`](https://www.w3.org/Tools/HTML-XML-utils/man1/hxwls "hxwls - list links in an HTML file") utility from the `html-xml-utils` package can list elements, attributes, and URIs as tab-separated values.